# How do I compute the summation of ${80\choose k}\cdot {k+1 \choose 31}$?

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

How do I compute the summation of ${80 \choose k}{ k+1 \choose 31}$?

I have it expanded in this way $\frac{80!}{k!(80-k)!} \cdot \frac{(k+1)!}{31!(k-30)!}$

Is there a way I can write this as an expression involving one or two binomial coefficients?

Comment: Try to rewrite it as a sum with respect to $t$ with $k =t +30 $.

Answer (score 3):

The $(k+1)!$ and $k!$ simplify a little to just $k+1$. The remaining binomial factorials in the bottom scream out that it would be great to introduce $50!$, since then they could all be incorporated into another binomial coefficient:

$$(k+1)\frac{80!\cdot50!}{50!\cdot(80-k)!\cdot31!\cdot(k-30)!}=(k+1)\binom{50}{80-k}\frac{80!}{50!\cdot31!}$$

Now if $31$ is separated from $31!$, we have a large constant binomial coefficient:

$$(k+1)\binom{50}{80-k}\binom{80}{50}\frac{1}{31}$$

Now reindex by $k\mapsto80-k$ to make the one binomial coefficient look nicer:

$$(81-k)\binom{50}{k}\binom{80}{50}\frac{1}{31}$$

Summing over $k$ that contribute nonzero terms:

$$\frac{1}{31}\binom{80}{50}\sum_{k=0}^{k=50}(81-k)\binom{50}{k}$$

Break this up over the $81$ and the $k$ and you can use simple summation formulas. The sum of binomial coefficients is a certain power of $2$. The sum of $k\binom{50}{k}$ is a certain power of $2$ multiplied by $50$. See [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinomialSums.html).

$$\frac{1}{31}\binom{80}{50}\left(81\cdot2^{50}-50\cdot2^{49}\right)=\frac{1}{31}\binom{80}{50}\cdot2^{49}\cdot112=\frac{112\cdot2^{49}}{31}\binom{80}{50}$$